# Dynamic creation of a table in SQLite3

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

In the following way, I am creating a table :

```
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "create table demo (name text, age integer);", NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
   printf("Error: %s:Unable to create the table\n", zErrMsg);
}
```

Output:
           **Table**:    **name** **age**

- I want to create a table dynamically with the different names & age:

  Example:
          **Table:  John 20**
- Is it possible to create it dynamically?
- Requirement :

We want to create a table with column name that can be changed dynamically i.e 
from our application we will get a name and we want to create a column in my table with that name.
We are facing data type conflict.

Example :

From our application we will get a character array :

char a[5] = "John".

We need to create a column with John as column name.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using SQLite, every table creation event is dynamic.  What is perhaps not obvious is that existing tables can be (dynamically) modified in certain (highly restricted) ways -- see the `ALTER` command for details.

Comment: Could you explain your question more clearly? What do you mean by dynamically creating tables?

Comment: Thanks @AlanBirtles. 
- I want to create a table as mentioned below :

    char a[10]  = "John";

    int b =10;
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "create table demo (a text,  b  integer);", NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg);
   
- Every time the value of a & b will be changed.

Comment: Do you want to create a table or insert a row into a table or do both at the same time? You should edit clarifications into your orignal question rather than adding comments which don't allow line breaks or code formatting

Comment: I think you're actually wanting to **insert** values into a table, not create new tables.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn. But we are not trying to insert the values into a table. We are trying to create a table with column name with respect to input from our application.

Comment: hi @AlanBirtles . Changed the query as you suggested.

Comment: the sqlite query is just a string, you can build the string however you like, it doesn't need to be hard coded (watch out for SQL injection though)